# How to find highest reputation user given specific tag?

Tags: support

I am not sure if this is a duplicate, but I have not been able to find a way to filter reputation rankings by tag. Specifically, my curiosity is about JavaScript. Jon Skeet, as everyone knows, has the highest ranking in C# and Java, but I would like to know who has the highest reputation in JavaScript.

Although I know somebody could point me out who has the highest reputation, but I suppose this is going to change over time, I want to know if there is a way to filter or use operators in search, etc.

Comment: I don't know if this will translate to the highest rep _but_ https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info on the right side is "Top Answerers" and T.J. Crowder is currently at the top.

Comment: Or a better link would be this one https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/topusers